# Passing event to second level child component

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

In my Angular 2 ngrx app, I have structure with nested elements:

```
parentContainer.ts
@Component({
  template: `<parent-component
    (onEvent)="onEvent($event)"
  ></parent-component>`,
})

class ParentContainer {
  constructor(private store: Store<IState>) { }

  private onEvent = (payload: IEventPayload) {
    this.store.dispatch(new EventAction(payload));
  }
}

parentComponent.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  templateUrl: 'patent.html',
})

class ParentComponent {
  @Output() private onEvent = new EventEmitter<IEventPayload>();
}

patent.html
<div>
  ...some content

  <child-component></child-component>
</div>
```

In this case, I can emit an event from the parent component, but I need to do it from the child component.

Is there a way to pass an event through a parent component to a child component and then use something like this: `this.onEvent.emit({... some payload})`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your patent.html you can let the child-component emit directly through onEvent like this:

```
<child-component (onChildEvent)="onEvent.emit($event)">
</child-component>
```

Answer (score 2):

**In child component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
```

...
in class body:

```
@Output() onMyEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

...
call event

```
this.onMyEvent.emit(true);
```

**In template:**

```
<child-component (onChildEvent)="onEvent.emit($event)">
</child-component>
```

**In parent component:**

```
  onChildEvent(boolean){
    alert("Event now!");
  }
```